# jquery hyperlinking like google

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, datagrid

have you ever noticed how in gmail, as the emails are updated in your inbox, you get a  hyperlink to it like so:

http://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox/23e0377656b24123

and if you click on that link it doesnt reload the page?

Can you do that with jquery and a datagrid?
So that you get links to items in your grid, which is populated asynchronously. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft also has AJAX history manipulation as of .net 3.5 sp1. [Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310856.aspx). Take a look at [Sys.Application.addHistoryPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488025.aspx) and [Sys.Application.navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488024.aspx). Actually AJAX-ifying your grid is really up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need an AJAX history library - [here's YUI's](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/history/), and a quick Google found [this one for jQuery](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html) (there are likely others if that one doesn't suit your needs exactly).